# pgfplots and tikz: clipping a named plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, path-clipping

I would like to clip along a `\addplot` line made by `pgfplots`.  I am not sure entirely how to do this since my tries have failed.  What have done so far is below.

```
\documentclass[tikz, convert = false]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.10}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    no marks,
    axis x line = center,
    axis y line = center,
    xmin = 0,
    xmax = 5,
    xlabel = {x},
    ylabel = {y}
    ]
    \addplot[blue, samples = 500, smooth, name path global = pinvx]
    gnuplot[domain = .5:5] {1/x};
    \addplot[red, samples = 500, smooth, name path global = ninvx]
    gnuplot[domain = .5:5] {-1/x};
    \legend{$\frac{1}{x}$, $\frac{-1}{x}$}

    \path[name path = line1] (axis cs:1.6, 1) -- (axis cs:1.6, -1);
    \path[name path = line2] (axis cs:1.75, 1) -- (axis cs:1.75, -1);
    \path[name intersections = {of = pinvx and line1, by = P1}];
    \path[name intersections = {of = ninvx and line1, by = P2}];
    \path[name intersections = {of = pinvx and line2, by = P3}];
    \path[name intersections = {of = ninvx and line2, by = P4}];

    \draw[green, opacity =.7] (P1) -- (P2);
    \draw[green, opacity =.7] (P3) -- (P4);

    \begin{scope}
      \clip pinvx;
      \fill[green, opacity =.7] (P1) -- (P3) -- (1.75, 0) -- (1.6, 0);
    \end{scope}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My end goal is to fill the area between the lines and the `1/x` and `-1/x` plots.  I tried using clip with the first plot name but that doesn't work.

Here is the plot with out the attempt of shading the area.

[image]

Comment: You might want to have a look at the PGF library `fillbetween`.

Comment: @HenriMenke that worked thanks.  Do you want to make it an answer?

Comment: Answered using `fillbetween`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `fillbetween` library of `pgfplots`, which is pretty straight forward to use:

1. Name the paths e.g. `A` and `B`
2. `\addplot fill between [of=A and B,...];`, where `...`stands for other options.

For more information confer to section 5.6 "Fill between" on page 364 of the [`pgfplots` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf).

## Implementation

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    no marks,
    axis x line = center,
    axis y line = center,
    xmin = 0,
    xmax = 5,
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = $y$
    ]
    \addplot[blue, samples = 500, smooth, name path global = pinvx]
    gnuplot[domain = .5:5] {1/x};
    \addplot[red, samples = 500, smooth, name path global = ninvx]
    gnuplot[domain = .5:5] {-1/x};
    \legend{$\frac{1}{x}$, $\frac{-1}{x}$}

    \addplot fill between [of=pinvx and ninvx,soft clip={domain=1.6:1.75}];
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

Answer (score 6):

This is is a result by `clip`. First, you need to define a clip area, whose coordinates are associated to the green lines. Then you draw and fill the two functions with `\closedcycle` so that the areas below the curve is filled. However, the real resulting clip area are the intersection of aforementioned areas -- The rectangle, areas below 1/x and -1/x.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, convert = false]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.8}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    no marks,
    axis x line = center,
    axis y line = center,
    xmin = 0,
    xmax = 5,
    xlabel = {x},
    ylabel = {y}
    ]
    \addplot[blue, samples = 500, smooth, name path global = pinvx,domain = .5:5] {1/x};
    \addplot[red, samples = 500, smooth, name path global = ninvx, domain = .5:5] {-1/x};
    \legend{$\frac{1}{x}$, $\frac{-1}{x}$}

    \path[name path = line1] (axis cs:1.6, 1) -- (axis cs:1.6, -1);
    \path[name path = line2] (axis cs:1.75, 1) -- (axis cs:1.75, -1);
    \path[name intersections = {of = pinvx and line1, by = P1}];
    \path[name intersections = {of = ninvx and line1, by = P2}];
    \path[name intersections = {of = pinvx and line2, by = P3}];
    \path[name intersections = {of = ninvx and line2, by = P4}];

    \draw[green, opacity =.7] (P1) -- (P2);
    \draw[green, opacity =.7] (P3) -- (P4);

    \begin{scope}
      \clip (axis cs: 1.6,-1) rectangle (axis cs:1.75,1);
    \addplot[samples = 500, smooth, name path global = pinvx,domain = .5:5,fill=green, opacity =.7] {1/x}\closedcycle;
    \addplot[samples = 500, smooth, name path global = ninvx, domain = .5:5,fill=green, opacity =.7] {-1/x}\closedcycle;
    \end{scope}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```