# Fill in between polar curves

Tags: tikz-pgf, fillbetween, polarplot

I am trying to fill in space between a pair of spiral curves in `tikz`.  I have tried using the `fillbetween` library but it just shades in the whole spiral.  Does anyone have a hint they could offer?  Thanks.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}  
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
   \begin{polaraxis}[hide axis]
    \addplot [mark=none,domain=0:720,samples=600,thick,gray] {0.5*x};
    \addplot [mark=none,domain=0:720-180,samples=600,thick,gray] {-0.667*x};    

    %\addplot [mark=none,domain=0:720,samples=600,thick,gray] {-0.5*x};     
    %\addplot [mark=none,domain=0:720-180,samples=600,thick,gray] {0.667*x}; 

    \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Looks like a good first question, too. It has a complete but minimal example which always makes people happy ;).

Comment: I feel like the named paths/fill between answer in this question ought to hold the key, but I just can’t get it to work: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172883/9668 :-/

Comment: I have to say, you can come up with some really interesting filling patterns if you play with this. Too bad none of them are the right one :(.

Answer (score 6):

In the meantime, here is a solution with MetaPost. Since the syntax of Tikz and MetaPost have many similarities, it may help to provide the desired solution.

The key point is to append the two spirals (one of them reverted), close the resulting path (`--cycle` instruction) and then fill it:

```
fill spiral1--reverse spiral2--cycle withcolor .8white;
```

I have inserted the MetaPost code into a LuaLaTeX program for typesetting convenience:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
  \mplibsetformat{metafun}
\begin{document}
  \begin{mplibcode}
    vardef polarfcn(expr tmin, tmax, tstep)(text f_t) =
      save t; t := tmin;
      (f_t*cos t, f_t*sin t)
      forever: hide(t := t + tstep) exitunless t <= tmax;
        .. (f_t*cos t, f_t*sin t)
      endfor
      if t - tstep < tmax: hide(t := tmax) .. (f_t*cos t, f_t*sin t) fi
    enddef;
    u := cm;
    beginfig(1);
      path spiral[]; 
      spiral1 = polarfcn(0, 4pi, 4pi/600)(.5t) scaled u;
      spiral2 = polarfcn(0, 3pi, 3pi/600)(-2/3t) scaled u;
      fill spiral1--reverse spiral2--cycle withcolor .8white;
      draw spiral1; draw spiral2;
    endfig; 
  \end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

**Edit** Here is a variant (with the same output), inspired by Thruston's remark.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
  \begin{mplibcode}
    vardef polarpnt(expr r, t) = r*dir t enddef;
    vardef polarfcn(expr tmin, tmax, tstep)(text r) =
      save t; t := tmin;
      polarpnt(r, t)
      forever: hide(t := t + tstep) exitif t > tmax; .. polarpnt(r, t) endfor
      if t - tstep < tmax: hide(t := tmax) .. polarpnt(r, t) fi
    enddef;
    beginfig(1);
      path spiral[]; 
      spiral1 = polarfcn(0, 720, 1)(.5t);
      spiral2 = polarfcn(0, 540, 1)(-2/3t);
      fill spiral1 .. reverse spiral2 .. cycle withcolor .8white;
      draw spiral1; draw spiral2;
    endfig; 
  \end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could make the spirals rather more simply with something like: `spiral1 = (0,0) for t = 0 step 3 until 720: -- ( 1/2t,0) rotated t endfor;`

Comment: Also, it probably would look slightly neater if you splice the spiral path segments with `..` rather than `--`.

Comment: @Thruston As for your second point, since the two spirals theoretically share their extremities, it makes (or it seems to make) no difference. As for the first point, you're quite right I'll post your alternative coding.

Comment: The path splicing point was just that `..` is simpler (because `--` is defined to be `{curl 1}..{curl 1}`).  But you are right, for such a short connection it probably makes no difference.

Comment: @Thruston I've posted the alternative. you may think I've complicated your suggestion, but I still wanted a general macro drawing any polar function, not necessarily starting at angle 0, but at any angle `tmin`, and necessarily stopping at `tmax` exactly — not before it, whatever the value of `tstep`. Also, I've used radians, because using degrees here would have required a big scaling.

Comment: @Thruston Note that the Metafun format is now only here because of the `pi`  number which is not defined in the plain format. I could have defined it myself: `pi := 3.14159265;`. But Metafun has a more precise value in store in case we use one of the floating-point number systems.

Comment: @Thruston Finally I decided for angles in degrees. The angle values are big,  but when they are combined with the PostScript big point default unit of MetaPost, the figure's resulting size is quite correct. So Metafun is not needed any more.

Answer (score 6):

I did manage to get the tikz code working.  Below is the code.  Thanks for the hints everyone.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
   \begin{polaraxis}[hide axis]
   \begin{scope}[]
        \addplot+[mark=none,domain=0:720,samples=100,line width=1pt,gray,name path=B] {0.5*x};
    \addplot+ [mark=none,domain=720-180:0,samples=100,thick,gray,name path=A] {-0.667*x};   
    \tikzfillbetween[of=A and B,on layer=,split,every even segment/.style={fill=none,draw=gray}]{gray}  
  \end{scope}
    \end{polaraxis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: swirl]

Comment: Your solution doesn't work at me (I copy/past it in my WinEdt editor). I receive error: ! Missing number, treated as zero. <to be read again> \advance \end{polaraxis}. The error is the same if I use solution shown pp. 371 in pgfplots manual adopted to your polar coordinate system.